# OpenVPN client and server running simultaneously on one server

Tags: openvpn

I have some problems with OpenVPN.

I have installed the OpenVPN client and server. If they are working separately, then it's fine, but if I try to connect both, one is not working. For example, if the OpenVPN client connects to a paid VPN, users can't connect to the server.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.226.1   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       192.168.226.1   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1
176.x.x.x  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.226.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun1
```